# Can the Javascript `userAgent` differ from a browser's header request

Tags: javascript, browser, http-headers, user-agent, navigator

Is there any plausible circumstance in which the `navigator` `userAgent` reported by Javascript could be different from the one sent as User-Agent Header.

Part of the reason I am asking is that: I have an app that collects the User Agent from JS to report back to the server. It's not necessary in most legit cases. However, could they actually differ or lie?

`navigator.userAgent` being 'read only' makes the change unlikely. I am just wondering if a hacker or an extension could in fact do so, on common browsers or a headless browser, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is an answer from my own tests and research. There are three types of user agent differences between header and client side in the wild:

The short UA strings policy by IE sending a [pre and post platform registry value tokens to the server to improves compatibility and network performance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9s-user-agent-string/). With the extended UA string provided through `navigator.userAgent`. They then added the ability to add [extension tokens](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/10/07/the-user-agent-string-use-and-abuse/).

---

The Tor Browser for iOS sends a Windows Desktop Firefox user agent by default.
Currently: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0`

Javascript however reports a generic Safari Mobile web view user agent.

---

UCMini (U2) send a UCWeb User Agent with the request such as:

`UCWEB/2.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 7_1 like Mac OS X; en; iPad3,6) U2/1.0.0 UCBrowser/9.3.1.344`

While the client side reports this wackadoodle:

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; zh-CN; r:1.2.3.4) Gecko/`

Answer (score 3):

yes, in case of incomplete user-agent spoofing.

browser addons like

- [Custom UserAgent String](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/custom-user-agent-revived/)
- [UAControl](http://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/252542/index.html) [outdated]
- [ua-site-switch](https://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/371723/index.html) [outdated]

will only change user-agent in http-header, but not in javascript variables

- navigator.userAgent
- navigator.appCodeName
- navigator.appName
- navigator.appVersion
- navigator.platform
- navigator.vendor
- navigator.vendorSub

for a [more] complete user-agent spoofing, also change the javascript variables:

- [User-Agent JS Fixer](http://legacycollector.org/firefox-addons/378075/index.html) [outdated]
- user script for greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Change navigator.userAgent
// @namespace   Rob W
// @description Changes navigator.userAgent to IE on IEGallery.com
// @match       http://www.iegallery.com/*
// @run-at      document-start
// @grant       none
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'userAgent', {
    value: 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)'
});
```

test pages:

- [show javascript user agent variables](https://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/features/test/)
- [show client http headers](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. A bunch of IE versions at least reported plugins only in the javascript one.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/10/07/the-user-agent-string-use-and-abuse/